# How to avoid range overflow of long etc in Java?

Tags: java

```java
public static long linearCountWays(int rows, int cols){
    // count grid ways in linear time

    // total permutations (ways) = (rows-1+cols-1)!;
    // repeating permutations (ways) = (rows-1)!*(cols-1)!
    // total ways = total ways / repeating ways

    // will return wrong answer for greater n/m whose factorial overflow the range of long. How can we solve this?

    return factorial(rows+cols-2) / (factorial(rows-1)*factorial(cols-1));
}
```

I have this code for finding out ways possible to travel n x m grid from (0, 0) to (n-1,m-1), but this code is not giving correct output for large values of n or m whose factorial overflow the range of long. How can we solve this issue in Java?

Example:

[image]

For input of n=15, m=15: Correct answer by counting all ways through recursive function is 40116600, but time complexity is O(2^(n+m)) which is not acceptable so I'm calling the linearCountWays method for same n & m and it shows 1455.

Comment: You may be interested in [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just looking at your problem again... I wonder if you can harness the fact that the numerator and denominator cancel?

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("1")

for (int i = rows; i <= cols-2; i++)
    bi = bi.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));        
return bi;
```

and then divide by `factorial(cols-1)`
This could avoid the overflow problem and speed up in many cases?

Comment: Nitpicking here, but you can use [`BigInteger.ONE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html#ONE) instead of `new BigInteger("1")`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigInteger.html) instead of `long`.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `BigInteger`:

```
static BigInteger fact(int num) {
     
    // Initializing BigInteger class
    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("1");       
    /*
     * Inside for loop, we are starting the loop from i = 1
     * and multiplying bi with the value of “i” and then incrementing
     * the value of “i” by 1.
     * This is repeated until “i” becomes equal or greater than the number num.
     */
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
        bi = bi.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));        
    return bi;
    
}
```

taken from
https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/java-integer-and-java-biginteger/

Answer (score 2):

Instead of just calling a factorial method, you can do the multiplications and divisions step by step to avoid intermediate results that exceed the range of a long.  You may be able to use Guava's [`LongMath.binomial`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/math/LongMath.html#binomial(int,int)), for example.

Comment: The implementation is here: https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/math/LongMath.java#L796-L978. Make sure to respect its license if you copy from it!